# Github Actions and git clone issue

Tags: terraform, github-actions

Having some problems using git clone from within a Github Actions, i get the following no matter what i try:

The code that fails in my main.yml:

```
jobs:
 terraform:
   name: 'Terraform with Github Actions!'
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   steps:
   - name: 'Login to Azure'
    uses: azure/login@v1
    with:
      creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
  - name: 'Checkout'
    uses: actions/checkout@master
  - name: 'Preparing blueprint-environment'
    run: |
      snip
      git clone git@github.com:ourcompany/whateverrepo.git
```

Error message:

git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).

Ive seen many posts on adding ssh-keys, but thats locally, not in a ubuntu-release running from Github actions - what am i missing here? I cant generate ssh-keys and add the private key on the fly to the Github repo-settings, how can i fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need to checkout two repositories I would recommend using `checkout` again to a relative path. See the documentation to [checkout multiple repos side by side](https://github.com/actions/checkout#Checkout-multiple-repos-side-by-side). You may need to use a `repo` scoped [Personal Access Token (PAT)](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line)

```
  - name: 'Checkout'
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
  - name: 'Preparing blueprint-environment'
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      token: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
      repository: ourcompany/whateverrepo
      path: whateverrepo
```

If it's really necessary, [Deploy keys](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#deploy-keys) can be used to clone a repository via SSH.

1. [Create a new SSH key pair](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#generating-a-new-ssh-key) for your repository. Do not set a passphrase.
2. Copy the contents of the public key (.pub file) to a new repository [deploy key](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#deploy-keys) and check the box to "Allow write access."
3. Add a secret to the repository containing the entire contents of the private key.
4. As shown in the example below, configure `actions/checkout` to use the deploy key you have created.

```
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ssh-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
```

Comment: so this token that needs to be added, is that just the similar token from the blueprint-repo, now also added to the current repo that wants to check out the blueprint? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: The [PAT](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line) needs to be created on an account that has write access to the blueprint-repo.

Comment: Quick followup, im having trouble accessing the PAT through variable interpolation - the PATs are created for the user through developer settings, should i still be able to use {{ secrets.PAT }}? This seems to be for the secrets created on the repo only?

Comment: Once the PAT is created you need to add that as a secret to the repository where the workflow runs. You can name the secret whatever you like. I used `PAT` in the example.

Comment: and then i can use {{ secrets.whatevername }} in my .yml to access that private repo?